# How to fetch Enqueue Count for ActiveMQ?

Tags: java, activemq-classic

Can someone please help me how to fetch the `Enqueue Count` for a particular queue in Active MQ?

Here is my code:

```
BrokerService broker = new BrokerService()
String queueName= "queue.Test"
ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory('ACTIVEMQ URL')
Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection()
connection.start()
Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE)
ActiveMQDestination requestDestination = session.createTopic(queueName)
QueueViewMBean view = (QueueViewMBean)broker.getDestination(requestDestination)
println("Count = "+view.getEnqueueCount())
```

But this does not seem to be working. How can I fix it?

Comment: "does not seem to be working" - please include details of the problem.  "it doesn't work" is too vague.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be trying to cast ActiveMQ JMS client resources into JMX MBeans which of course would never work.  You need to use [JMX](http://activemq.apache.org/jmx.html) to access the management capabilities of the broker.

Some examples of using the MBeans can be found in the [unit tests](https://github.com/apache/activemq/blob/master/activemq-unit-tests/src/test/java/org/apache/activemq/broker/jmx/MBeanTest.java) of the broker